# cannot get the text box values from react

Tags: reactjs, forms, state, submit, setstate

this is my code to check the front end text box values and when i run this it gives out the error "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" anyone have an idea about this plz. I know this is a very basic task but i am a beginner in react so i really appreciate the help

```
class products extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onChangeCustomerName = this.onChangeCustomerName.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCustomerCountry = this.onChangeCustomerCountry.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            customerName:'',
            customerCountry:''
        }
    }


    onChangeCustomerName(e){
        this.setState({
            customerName : e.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeCustomerCountry(e){
        this.setState({
            customerCountry : e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const customer = {
            customerName: this.state.customerName,
            customerCountry: this.state.customerCountry
        }

        console.log(customer);

        window.location = '/';
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>New Cusotmer Details</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className = "form-group">
                        <label>Customer Name:</label>
                        <input type = "text" required className="form-control" value = {this.state.customerName} onChange = {this.onChangeCustomerName} />
                    </div>
                    <div className = "form-group">
                        <label>Customer Country:</label>
                        <input type = "text" required className="form-control" value = {this.state.customerCountry} onChange = {this.onChangeCustomerCountry} />
                    </div>
                    <div className = "form-group">
                        <input type = "submit" value = "Add" className="btn btn-primary" onChange = {this.onChangeCustomerName} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bound `onSubmit` method to the component instance in constructor. But you're expecting the context to be the component instance here:

```
const customer = {
   customerName: this.state.customerName,
   customerCountry: this.state.customerCountry
}
```

Try adding:

```
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```